# Defending against "unclean" local builds?

Tags: c#, .net, build, msbuild

(This is about local builds on dev machines, NOT builds being done externally on a build server as blessed builds.)

In normal Visual Studio/C# development, the local build system "just works."  However, on rare occasions***, the built code behaves erratically. (Erratically = not as the source code says)  Maybe it produces weird errors, produces output that shouldn't be possible, or acts as though recent code changes never happened.  These builds can be remedied by doing a clean/rebuild.  However, since many solutions take drastically longer to do a full clean/rebuild than to trust the standard build system and simply "Build",
doing a full clean/rebuild every time isn't a practical option.

The problem comes when one of those "erratic" builds gets made and issues are seen.  Typically, the bugs get spotted, and developer resources start focusing on how this bizarre behavior could be happening based on the source code used to create it.  Since the initial developer can't figure out how the erratic behavior came from the source code, more resources get called in to hunt in futility for the bug in the source code.

Given that once a "non-clean" build goes erratic when built on a certain machine, it will typically continue to build erratically until a clean/rebuild is performed, *huge amounts of developer resources* can get sucked into the futility before someone throws their hands up and says "I'm going to try some low-probability thing, because we're grasping at straws here", tries cleaning and rebuilding, and suddenly the erratic behavior goes away.

Assuming:

1. Because of speed, "build" will be chosen over clean/rebuild except when there is an explicit reason for clean/rebuild
2. The erratic builds happen rarely enough that convincing devs to habitually clean/rebuild daily would be a fruitless endeavor
3. Making builds and finding errors is a routine part of development and therefore, nothing "stands out" about spotting a build bug that needs to be fixed when the true cause is a corrupt build.  Similarly, bringing in additional resources for debugging a hard bug is also routine and not anything that stands out.

Are there ways to defend against this?  Are their ways to detect when the temp/cached files that "cleaning" deletes are out of date and problematic?
Are their ways (beyond telling devs to "remember to try cleaning and rebuilding") to prevent a huge snowball of resources from checking the source code for non-existent issues in the code?

***In the last 12 months, I've seen 3 or 4 occurrences of erratic builds wasting >> one developer/day before the cause is found.  In the same time, there were probably 3-5000 developer builds that worked normally.

Comment: Is the build from the build machine OK? If so, shelve current changes and rebuild locally. Is it OK now? If yes, then your local changes are to blame. If no then try a  local clean rebuild.

Comment: Seems odd your team are having high incidents.  Using any unusual post-build events?  Tools?  Resharper Build?  I know that latter is flaky

Comment: Agree with MickyD - this is usually more related to build tools outside of msbuild itself. 3rd party add-ons, translators and the like.

Comment: @MatthewWatson  The build server doesn't have the issue because it starts every build in a new empty directory so that stale temp files can never be an issue.  However, it takes >10 min to build that way compared 10-20 seconds for a local "build".  Completely impracticable for rapid debugging of development code.

Comment: @MickyD  Local builds work great >99.9% of the time, certainly not a high incidence rate.  But that is the issue:  Because it is so rare, when it happens, we get blindsided by it.  I'm trying to figure out a rational way to prevent these rare issues from being so disproportionately costly to developer resources.

Comment: @PaulSwetz I don't disagree.  3rd party add-ons, and new versions/updates of Visual Studio quite likely play a part.  However, avoiding version updates and utilities would cause more issues that it would solve.  With today's development cycles, nobody has the luxury to assume any tool doesn't have at least a minuscule error rate.

Comment: Agreed, though that's not the point I'm making.  I'm saying that it is unusual for a whole team to be experiencing this, hence my thought on what it is you are doing exactly.

Comment: It sounds to me like you could have incorrect dependencies between different assemblies defined in different solutions. Do you have every project in one big solution or do you have multiple solutions?